# Is there a way to turn off auto-conversion of objects to strings in php 5.2?

Tags: php, object

I'm using a compiler that has a slightly older version of PHP than my dev machine (5.1.3 vs. 5.2.6 IIRC). That version doesn't do the auto-conversion, which can result in some sneaky bugs in the compiled version. I'd rather not downgrade my dev box, but if I can somehow turn that off, that might be helpful in finding those earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define the [`__toString()` function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) on your classes?

Comment: It _is_ defined. That's what allows 5.2 to do the version. 5.1 still doesn't, unless you're in an echo or print context. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring

Comment: er... by "version" I mean "conversion"

Comment: Oh, and by the link, I'm referring to the "It is worth noting" section below the example code. 

(It would be nice to be able to edit these comments.)

Comment: OH. I see what you're saying now. I'm sorry, I misunderstood before. Let me think if there's any way around that...